# Why anaconda3 install python 2.7

Tags: macos, anaconda

I downloaded and installed `Anaconda3-2019.03-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg` which should normally install python 3.7. But oddly this is not the case :

```
(base) iMac-de-Bibi:~ ac$ which python

/Users/ac/anaconda3/bin/python

(base) iMac-de-Bibi:~ ac$ /Users/ac/anaconda3/bin/python --version

Python 2.7.16 :: Anaconda, Inc
```

Any help would be appreciated

Note : it's my first anaconda installation on this machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You might have mistakenly downloaded and installed the wrong Anaconda distribution.
2. You might have changed the Python version in the base environment after the initial installation, by doing something like this:

   ```
   conda activate base
   conda install python=2.7
   ```

   - *Update: As reported in a comment, installing `pyside` downgrades Python.*
3. Have you correctly activated the base environment, and not messed with PATH or PYTHONPATH? I'm not sure about it, but `python` might be a script that calls the actual Python interpreter. It could pick the wrong one if search paths are off.

In general, I recommend to install Miniconda and create custom environments. Then you can choose whichever Python version you want for each environment, and don't care which one is in the base environment.

Comment: Thanks for the return but no, I downloaded the good pkg (the created directory is anaconda3 and not anaconda2). I destroyed /Users/ac/anaconda3 and redid a new install (in /Application this time) and miracle, I have python 3.7 ...

Comment: I understood what had happened. After the first installation, I installed pyside (conda install pyside) and this installation replaces python 3.7 with python 2.7. From now on, I only work in a virtual environment !

Comment: @Bibi29 Thanks for reporting back. So basically a variant of my item 2 :-) I'd be nice if you upvote or accept my answer. Then your question will no longer appear in the list of unanswered question.